# What is faster/more efficient/better when it comes to these $.each loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a Javascript object which looks like this:

```
var a = {
  b: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  c: [10,11,12,13,14,15]
}
```

to loop through both arrays (I want to loop through every value!) I use `$.each`, but I can do this:

```
// Option A:
$.each(a, function(i, d){
  $.each(d, function(j, e){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

or this

```
// Option B:
$.each(a.b, function(k, f){
  console.log(f)
})

$.each(a.c, function(l, g){
  console.log(g)
})
```

Both generate exactly the same output, but which of these two versions is faster/more efficient/better?

Is there any difference at all?

Or is there a more faster/more efficient/better way (without `$.each`)?

Comment: i've the feeling this question has been answered before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that using some kind of `each` is always slower than a for loop. SM and V8 can do pretty good inlining
as long as you are not ruining it for them - a custom implementation of each taking advantage of the fact can run [just as fast
as a for loop](http://jsperf.com/for-foreach-jqeach).

With that said, jQuery `$.each` doesn't take advantage of the fact and it is slow. Avoid in performance sensitive situations.

As for your question, I expect the second one to be slightly faster in JITs because it avoids reflection and uses static property access which is taken advantage of by every modern engine. $.each is so slow that the difference isn't really pronounced here.

http://jsperf.com/129031290419034

Answer (score 8):

The most efficient way is to use a simple and native `for` loop. Avoid jQuery at all.

Comment: +1. OP - if you really want to see the performance difference, [test it yourself](http://jsperf.com)

Comment: I get the point, `for` loops are faster. But when it comes to `for` inside `for` loops. That doesn't change anything? Besides I know I can test myself but if someone already knows the answer that saves me a test doesn't it?

Comment: @GerardWesterhof If a `for` (or `while`) is faster than a `forEach`, a `for` inside a `for` is faster than a `forEach` inside a `forEach`, too. However, you need to consider variable name conflicts (unless you have `let` available to you).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can beat :

```
var i=0, arr=a.b, len=arr.length;   
for(; i<len; i++ ) { console.log(arr[i]) } ;
```

by the way, if you are in doubt, ask jsperf.
Here there's one test that shows a 5X / 10X increase :
     http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/9

Comment: "Nothing can beat", isn't really true now, is it?

Comment: :-) Well the jsperf link shows that the basic for loop is way ahead. What i mean is that any construct built on top of the basic for loop will be slower.

Comment: Yep, things built on top would be slower, but you have to be careful when you say "nothing" :P `sum = 0; sum += 1; sum += 2; sum += 3;` etc would be faster.. and specifically in your case, `(n * (n + 1)) / 2` would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If your real concern is speed then go for javascript's own for loop.
for your answer, I think Option b will be faster